# Update/refresh object in the VSCode watch panel programmatically from debug server

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I maintain a VSCode debugger extension for Roku's BrightScript language. Roku doesn't have a formal debug protocol, so my debugger uses the [telnet command-line utility](https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/debugging/debugging-channels.md) to issue various debugging commands (like print variable, continue, step, etc...). Since the Roku is a network device, and we are doing string parsing, every command is fairly slow compared to debugging an on-machine program like node or C#. As such, we try to lazy load data instead of eagerly loading data whenever possible.

Take this object for example:

```js
business = {
    employeeNames: ["Michael", "Jim", "Pam", "Dwight"],
    name: "Dunder Mifflin Paper Company"
}
```

When a user adds `business` to the watch panel, vscode issues an [evaluateRequest](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/blob/master/adapter/src/debugSession.ts#L741) for `"business"`. Behind the scenes, I run a telnet command `print business`, which returns the following:

```
<Component: roAssociativeArray> =
{
    employeeNames: <Component: roArray>
    name: "Dunder Mifflin Paper Company"
}
```

At this point, we know that `employeeNames` is an array, but we don't know its size, and shouldn't eagerly look up its size because that requires a separate command that would slow down the entire debugging experience.

[image]

Next, in the VSCode watch panel, the user expands the `employeeNames` property, and vscode calls [variablesRequest](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/blob/master/adapter/src/debugSession.ts#L729). My debug extension runs the telnet command `print business.employeeNames`, and it returns this:

```
<Component: roArray> =
[
    "Michael"
    "Jim"
    "Pam"
    "Dwight"
]
```

At this point, I want to update `employeeNames` type to show the array count, like this:
[image]

Here's the `DebugProtocol.Variable` that I would change in the debug extension...but I don't know how to send this to VSCode when VSCode hasn't asked for updates on this variable.

```js
//hardcoded for the sake of this question...is dynamic in actual code
var variableName = "business.employeeNames"
var arrayValues= getArrayValues(variableName); // ["Michael", "Jim", "Pam", "Dwight"]
let variable: DebugProtocol.Variable = {
    name: "employeeNames";
    evaluateName: "business.employeeNames";
    type: `roArray (${arrayValues})`;
    value: arrayValues;
    children: [];
}
```

I tried to trick vscode into re-requesting everything, but VSCode didn't request new variables because it was smart enough to realize that the `StoppedEvent` was at the same location where it was previously stopped.

```js
//send a continue
this.sendEvent(new ContinuedEvent(0, true));
//wait a short time
setTimeout(()=>{
    //send a stopped event
    this.sendEvent(new StoppedEvent('exception', threadId, exception.message));
}, 10);
```

As a debug extension author, from the debug extension code, how do I tell VSCode that a variable in the watch panel has changed, and needs to be refreshed?